# TABLE element 100% height of a min-height container

Tags: css, css-tables

This is such a simple (and a little stupid) question, but I can’t find a good answer.

How can I make a TABLE element stretch to 100% height of it’s parent container that has a min-height? Consider this:

```
<div>
    <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div { min-height:400px; background:yellow }
table { background:pink; height:100% }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/faynV/

I’m not really used to working with tables, so any help is appreciated...

Comment: Note that [`In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-min-height) - it *may* explain why it isn't working like you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
div{min-height:400px;height:400px;background:yellow}
table{background:pink;height:100%;width:100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/faynV/1/

Comment: It is must for parent element to have explicit height if child is using percentage.

Comment: No, I used min-height for a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Set html and body tag's height to 100% and then the outer container height. i.e.

```
body,html{height:100%;}
div{min-height:400px;height:100%;background:yellow}
table{background:pink;height:100%;}
```

however you need to set the height of the div same as min-height, if you are specific to fixed height. check [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-min-height)